# how to get alert and location.href to both work in the same script

Tags: javascript, php, alert, location-href

I have the following in a php controller:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Emails have been added to the database")';
echo 'location.href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/update.php"';
echo '</script>';

exit();
```

The alert by itself works and the location.href by itself works. When combined I just get a blank page and neither seems to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a ; at the end of the alert to separate the two lines:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Emails have been added to the database");';
echo 'location.href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/update.php"';
echo '</script>';

exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your console it will show you some undefined identifier because all your code becomes in one line without space

you could do this

```
        <?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Emails have been added to the database") ';
    echo "\n";
    echo ' window.location.href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/update.php"';
    echo '</script>';

    exit();
    ?>
```